# Android Studio - - Only 1 button plays sound in MainActivity

Tags: java, android, audio

Currently, I'm working on a simple Russian Roulette application.

It has three buttons:

- Spin -- Which just plays the sound of a spinning barrel (this works currently).
- Insert Round -- Places one bullet into the revolver (haven't gotten to that yet) and plays sound (works).
- Play -- Uses boolean that misfires or fires a round (if it fires a round, take a bullet away from revolver) entirely depending on chance and how many bullets are in the revolver. Currently I'm using a random number between 1 and 6, and 0 is the default rounds you start with when you start the app (so it includes the mechanic of having no rounds in the revolver).

Here is what my activity looks like:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Buttons of Main-activity displayed
    Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    one.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insert_Round);
    two.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fire_weapon);
    three.setOnClickListener(this);
    int rounds_left = 0;
}

//Let's make addition.
public static int add(int i) {
    i++;
    return i;
}

@Override
public void onClick (View v) {
    int rounds_left = 0;
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.spinner:
            //play spinner sound
            final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.spinnersound);
            mp1.start();
            break;
        case R.id.insert_Round:
            //play insert_round sound
            final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.insert_round_sound);
            mp2.start();
            //Adds one round into chamber (I need help here)
            break;
        case R.id.fire_weapon:
            //Random number between 1 and 6... *Click* or *Fire*
            Random rand = new Random();
            int  play_chances = rand.nextInt(7) + 1;
            if (play_chances < rounds_left) {
                final MediaPlayer mp4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fire_sound);
                mp4.start();
                //Take a bullet away (need help here too)
            } else {
                final MediaPlayer mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.misfire_sound);
                mp3.start();
            }
            break;
    }
}

}
```

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuIgU.png) is how it looks like so far.

---

I have two questions:

1. How do I make it so that when I press the Insert Round button, I can add 1 round to my `rounds_left`?

   I was able to create an addition method (Is that what this is called?) that makes this addition happen. I've tried to apply it several times to no avail.

   ```
   public static int add(int i) {
       i++;
       return i;
   }
   ```
2. How do I take a round away from my `rounds_left` after I have discharged my bullet?

Comment: You want to start with making `int rounds_left` a member variable (place it at the top of the class and outside of a method). Otherwise, it will be reset to 0 every time you click the button and is useless outside of onClick

Comment: I've changed int rounds_left  so that it is outside onClick. I've put it all the way up the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: inside of case R.id.insert_Round:

```
case R.id.insert_Round:
  if(rounds_left < 6)
    rounds_left++;
```

2: inside of case R.id.fire_weapon:

```
case R.id.fire_weapon:
    if(rounds_left > 1){
      //do stuff
      rounds_left--;
    } else {
      //play empty chamber sound
    }
```

Unsolicited Advice:

Instead of `one.setOnClickListener(this);` I recommend doing something more like:

```
one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          whateverMethodOrCodeYouWantToTriggerWhenUserClicksOne();
        }

two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          whateverMethodOrCodeYouWantToTriggerWhenUserClicksTwo();
        }
```

Your code will be much easier to read and maintain.

Also:

```
public static int add(int i) {
    i++;
    return i;
}
```

Code like this will haunt you or some poor maintainer someday. There's no need for this method. It's name is unclear, and it produces a bit of a side effect someone might not be expecting. Just increment `i` when appropriate without doing so with a custom method.